# PHP JSON string parsing

Tags: php, json

I'm having some trouble accessing elements in JSON.
Here's my code:

```
$raw_json = '{
        "players": [
            {
                "steamid": "76561197960435530",
                "communityvisibilitystate": 3,
                "profilestate": 1,
                "personaname": "Robin",
                "lastlogoff": 1365134746,
                "profileurl": "http://steamcommunity.com/id/robinwalker/",
                "avatar": "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/f1/f1dd60a188883caf82d0cbfccfe6aba0af1732d4.jpg",
                "avatarmedium": "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/f1/f1dd60a188883caf82d0cbfccfe6aba0af1732d4_medium.jpg",
                "avatarfull": "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/f1/f1dd60a188883caf82d0cbfccfe6aba0af1732d4_full.jpg",
                "personastate": 0,
                "realname": "Robin Walker",
                "primaryclanid": "103582791429521412",
                "timecreated": 1063407589,
                "loccountrycode": "US",
                "locstatecode": "WA",
                "loccityid": 3961
            }
    }
}';
$data = json_decode($raw_json);
print $data->players{'realname'};
```

My question is - how can I access arrays like personname or realname?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're using curly braces instead of brackets.  the right syntax would be

```
$data->players['realname']
```

That said, you have an object inside the array so accessing it by key wouldn't work either.  You'd need something like this

```
$data->players[0]
```

Further, your json was invalid so you should fix it.  a helpful tool to validate json is this http://json.parser.online.fr/

Answer (score 1):

First up, your `JSON` is not in a valid format, and that decode is not even working. Try

```
<?php
$raw_json = '
{
    "players": [
        {
            "steamid": "76561197960435530",
            "communityvisibilitystate": 3,
            "profilestate": 1,
            "personaname": "Robin",
            "lastlogoff": 1365134746,
            "profileurl": "http://steamcommunity.com/id/robinwalker/",
            "avatar": "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/f1/f1dd60a188883caf82d0cbfccfe6aba0af1732d4.jpg",
            "avatarmedium": "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/f1/f1dd60a188883caf82d0cbfccfe6aba0af1732d4_medium.jpg",
            "avatarfull": "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/f1/f1dd60a188883caf82d0cbfccfe6aba0af1732d4_full.jpg",
            "personastate": 0,
            "realname": "Robin Walker",
            "primaryclanid": "103582791429521412",
            "timecreated": 1063407589,
            "loccountrycode": "US",
            "locstatecode": "WA",
            "loccityid": 3961
        }
    ]
}
';
$data = json_decode($raw_json);
print_r( $data->players[0]); // or
echo $data->players[0]->personaname;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data = json_decode($raw_json);
echo $data->players['realname'];
```

Or you can see the data format by

```
print_r($data);
```

or

```
var_dump($data);
```